# Is there a way to make Gitlab CI run only when I commit an actual file?

Tags: gitlab-ci

New to Gitlab CI/CD.

What is the proper construct to use in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to ensure that my validation job runs only when a "real" checkin happens?

What I mean is, I observe that the moment I create a merge request, say—which of course creates a new branch—the CI/CD process runs.  That is, the *branch creation itself*, despite the fact that no files have changed, causes the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to be processed and pipelines to be kicked off.

Ideally I'd only want this sort of thing to happen when there is actually a change to a file, or a file addition, etc.—in common-sense terms, I don't want CI/CD running on silly operations that don't actually really change the state of the software under development.

I'm passably familiar with `except` and `only`, but these don't seem to be able to limit things the way I want.  Am I missing a fundamental category or recipe?

Comment: You might want to subscribe and upvote this issue on their tracker: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid what you ask is not possible within Gitlab CI.

There could be a way to use the `CI_COMMIT_SHA` predefined variable since that will be the same in your new branch compared to your source branch.

Still, the pipeline will run before it can determine or compare SHA's in a custom script or condition.

Gitlab runs pipelines for branches or tags, not commits. Pushing to a repo triggers a pipeline, branching is in fact pushing a change to the repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: at least now I know the right mental model to use here. Maybe I can "filter" using the commit message? Looking for the right pattern to use here.

Comment: Yeah you could, just remember the filtering would also take place inside a job of a pipeline and thus it will need to run first. I personally don't mind pipelines running if you have enough runners. Also feel free to upvote and mark the answer if it suits you.

Comment: maybe it is a new feature but now you get only/ecxept changes - https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges